# HereAPI inconsistent cost matrix result for the same locations pair from/to

Tags: here-api

We experience different/inconsistent results calling HereAPI calculate matrix:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-matrix.html

Those two requests would get different results getting the cost matrix (https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json) for the location pair:

- from: start2=[49.5874311604988,6.36225600752937]
- to: destination4=[49.6199640866961,6.0752615082501]

req1Params =
          `{app_id=[abc], app_code=[xxx], mode=[fastest;truck;traffic:disabled], summaryAttributes=[traveltime,costfactor,distance], limitedWeight=[3.5], height=[2.815], width=[2.426], length=[6.945], start0=[49.99432,6.09711], start1=[50.04874,6.11873], start2=[49.5874311604988,6.36225600752937], start3=[50.1567001905827,6.0488119628559], start4=[49.6199640866961,6.0752615082501], start5=[50.05481,6.02723], destination0=[49.99432,6.09711], destination1=[50.04874,6.11873], destination2=[49.5874311604988,6.36225600752937], destination3=[50.1567001905827,6.0488119628559], destination4=[49.6199640866961,6.0752615082501], destination5=[50.05481,6.02723]}`

matrix result for start2 -> destination4:
`{"startIndex":2,"destinationIndex":4,"summary":{"distance":41400,"travelTime":3136,"costFactor":3176}}`

req2Params =
          `{app_id=[abc], app_code=[xxx], mode=[fastest;truck;traffic:disabled], summaryAttributes=[traveltime,costfactor,distance], limitedWeight=[3.5], height=[2.815], width=[2.426], length=[6.945], start0=[49.630539,6.13332], start1=[49.8302,5.84841], start2=[49.5874311604988,6.36225600752937], start3=[49.8503553810064,6.12768609880935], start4=[49.6199640866961,6.0752615082501], start5=[49.84435496244089,6.0966557264328], start6=[49.85112,6.09573], destination0=[49.630539,6.13332], destination1=[49.8302,5.84841], destination2=[49.5874311604988,6.36225600752937], destination3=[49.8503553810064,6.12768609880935], destination4=[49.6199640866961,6.0752615082501], destination5=[49.84435496244089,6.0966557264328], destination6=[49.85112,6.09573]}`

matrix result for start2 -> destination4:
`{"startIndex":2,"destinationIndex":4,"summary":{"distance":30737,"travelTime":2122,"costFactor":2162}}`

Has someone experienced something similar? Is it a bug or can someone explain why we have those inconsistent results?

update: add response details.

Comment: We receive different result for the same start/destination position pair, I added the details in the question. We detected up to 5 different results for this same pair.

Comment: The two request parameters are however different. first one 5 destination points and other one has 6. They are not same. Also the start points are showing variation. So the API is optimising every time to result the optimised route

Comment: Maybe we do not use the API as we should, doesn't the API provide the direct distance+travelTime between 2 positions, (in our case we specified fastest route)? Why would it be dependent on the other points in the request? The direct route between 2 positions is the same having 2, 10 or 100 other positions in the matrix request.

Comment: @Here Developer Support Do you have an explanation to those time/distance variations for the same start/destination location pair? The differences are quite big, up to 30%, so the chosen fastest routes are very different form one call to another.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying algorithm is using heuristic which drives search depending on the number of start/destinations. Different matrix sizes may give different results and this is expected. We are not able to ensure the same results for different sizes of matrices until we use this heuristic.

If you shorten a bit distance, the route will lead through different segments. This is because short distance may render more precise search in this case.